# git merge doesn't show up in commit history

Tags: git, github, merge

I'm pretty much new to git version control and trying to learn it ASAP.

Coming to my question, I have forked a repo and trying to sync my forked repo with the upstream repo. I followed the instructions as mentioned in https://help.github.com/articles/syncing-a-fork site.

After merging my repo using `git merge upstream/master` command, I don't see the delta commits in my repo commit history, however I see them when I run `git log` command.

Just trying to understand how git `merge` works. Appreciate if someone can throw their valuable thoughts onto this. Thanks in advance for your time and attention.

Comment: `git merge` merges on your working copy. You have to `git push` to your repo to see it appear there.

Comment: When you say "I don't see the delta commits in my repo commit history", which command are you using to see it?

Comment: Thanks @JBNizet. `git push` worked.
@janos, I mean when I login to my github application I don't see the merged commits history.

Answer (score 4):

```
git merge --no-ff
```

This makes a fast forward merge visible in the history.

Comment: Now I'm facing a different issue, actually the otherway what I posted. I could see the commit in the github repo history but not in my local working copy. When I run `git log` I don't see my last pushed commit which I see in the github repo.